# Why do commands in Try/Catch sometimes need -ErrorAction Stop and sometimes not?

Tags: windows, powershell, script

In the example below I want to `catch` the Error with `-ErrorAction Stop`. It worked perfectly in this case.

```
try
{
    Import-Module -ErrorAction Stop -Force nomodule.psm1
}
catch
{
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red "no module"

    $PSItem >> $env:HOMEPATH\AVSUB.log
    exit 1
}
```

But in the case below, I did not use `-ErrorAction Stop` and the `catch` block still ran.

```
try
{
    $var= broken_function
}
catch
{
   Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red "error"

   $PSItem >> $env:HOMEPATH\AVSUB.log
   exit 1
}
```

Why do I sometimes need to specify `-ErrorAction Stop` and sometimes not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are [Terminating](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/cmdlet/terminating-errors?view=powershell-7) and [Non-Terminating](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/understanding-non-terminating-errors-in-powershell/) Errors in PowerShell.

A terminating error is an error that halts the execution of a cmdlet, script or program. This will be caught by `Try {} Catch {}` without the need of `-ErrorAction Stop`.

Non-terminating errors allow PowerShell to continue the execution. You can catch them, by adding `-ErrorAction Stop`.

Here are two functions, one produces a terminating error, the other a non-terminating error.

```
# This will throw a terminating error
function TerminatingErrorExample {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param()
    Throw "I can't run like this!"
    Write-Host "This message will never be displayed, because it's after the terminating error."
}

# This will write a non-terminating error
function NonTerminatingErrorExample {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param($i = 5)
    if ($i -gt 4) {
        Write-Error "I expected a value less or equal to 4!"
    }
    Write-Host "However, I can still continue the execution"
}
```

If you're curious as to why I used `[CmdletBinding()]` in the functions, it's because without that, functions don't support `[<CommonParameters>]`, and `-ErrorAction Stop` is a CommonParameter.

Now we can wrap them in `Try {} Catch {}`

```
# Because the function produces a terminating error, the Catch block will run
Try {
    TerminatingErrorExample
} Catch {
    Write-Host "I got you!"
}

# Since the error here is non-terminating, the catch block won't run
Try {
    NonTerminatingErrorExample
} Catch {
    Write-Host "You won't see this message"
}

# Now the catch block will run, because we specifically say we want it to stop,
# even on a non-terminating error.
Try {
    NonTerminatingErrorExample -ErrorAction Stop
} Catch {
    Write-Host "Now you see this message."
}
```

If we run this, the return will look just like expected:

```
I got you!
NonTerminatingErrorExample : I expected a value less or equal to 4!
In Zeile:28 Zeichen:5
+     NonTerminatingErrorExample
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,NonTerminatingErrorExample

However, I can still continue the execution
Now you see this message.
```

Comment: That's very good answer. But I have a quesiton: I think this method is not working with `non-shell built-in commands` like `ffmpeg`. Because after a unsucessful process with `ffmpeg`, script can continue to the next commands. Is there a way to stop this too? Thank you.

Comment: @SerhatÇelik I don't have such a program to test this right now, but you can test if it works if you set `$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"` before the `Try/Catch` block and set it to `$ErrorActionPreference = "Continue"` again afterwards